# Lagrangian multipliers in complex least square

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, least-squares

We need to solve the following complex least square problem:\begin{align*}\min\limits_X&&\|Y-X\|^2\\\text{s.t.}&&X^TAX=0\end{align*}where the complex matrix  $Y$ and the real matrix $A$ are given.

**My Thoughts:**

Let $L=\textbf{Tr}\{YY^H-YX^H-XY^H+XX^H\}+\lambda(X^TAX)$ be the Lagrangian function. Thus, we have

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial X}=0 \Longrightarrow -Y^* + X^* + \lambda(A+A^T)X=0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial X^*}=0 \Longrightarrow -Y +X =0
\end{equation}

So we have $X=Y$.  Did we do something wrong? Can anyone help us? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I met similar issues several times in my engineering work. I am not a mathematician, but my interpretation is that the quantity $X^T A X$ is complex, and that trying to find a minimum of a complex value function by derivating it can only bring strange things. I was sometimes able to solve it by replaving the complex value quantity by its (real) square norm. But I would be happy too to get more detailed explanations

Comment: @Damien Thanks for your comments! This problem can be solved by replacing the complex value quantity by its square norm. But is this the optimal solution?